# Shopify: Get turnover/revenue total using API

Tags: api, shopify, scopes

I'm at a loss.

**Using the API:**
How do I fetch my **revenue/sales/turnover** for this day / week / month?

### [image]

**Additional info:**

I cannot find any API functionality that will do this job,
but I know that Shopify has various API 'namespaces' / 'scopes', some which seem to be undocumented, that they can provide access to, which would surely have the data I need:

- admin_notifications
- apps
- channels
- content
- customers
- disputes
- fulfillments
- gift_card_adjustments
- gift_cards
- inventory
- meta_tags
- orders
- products
- public_customers
- script_tags
- scripts
- shipping
- social_network_accounts
- taxes
- themes

Comment: Where do you want the data to be displayed?

Comment: The Shopify API is RESTful and outputs a JSON response. I would like this data to be accessible over HTTP to return a JSON response, which will be consumed by an application (in this case I will display it in a Google Sheet)

Comment: Yup, I aware of Shopify's RESTful API. You'd need to make GET calls from Google Sheets (using apps) to get the data. I can't help you more than that as I'm not well aware of Google Sheet Apps.

Comment: Thanks, I already have the appropriate functionality in Google Sheets, there are some scripts available that allow Google Sheets to fetch JSON responses after an Auth process -- so far all of that is working OK. The only problem now is Shopify's API doesn't give me the data I need.

Comment: There are a couple parameters you can try `created_at_max` and `created_at_min`.

Comment: @RichardWoolf: Shopify doesn't provide any api to do this? Are you interesting with a web crawler solution (use http to login then parse html and get the result)?

Comment: @HieuPham Are you referring to the workaround where, instead of fetching the turnover/revenue directly, I would instead fetch all the orders between 2 dates, and then iterate through all of them adding up the total revenue.
This is not a practical solution because the API has a limit on the number of records you can fetch per minute, so some applications (such as Google Sheets) wouldn't be able to handle that and even if it could, it is not practical if this data is going to be fetched often.
The Shopify admin shows this turnover data directly like I want, but not using the API.

Comment: So far the workaround I am using is to export a CSV file of all the orders for the dates I need, then copy-pasting it into a Google Sheet which my other Google Sheet will automatically fetch the turnover data. However this process is not automatic :(
Another workaround may be a 'web hook' where after every order, a new record appears in Google Sheets. I'm not sure how to do that using a webhook, but that would do the trick for me.

Comment: @HieuPham I have read your comment more carefully now. Thank you for this suggestion. A webcrawler could work as a workaround: it is not an ideal solution. However, out of interest, can you tell me about some of the architecture of this solution, such as where the web crawler would store its results and what would the web crawler run on (would it be a Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey script that I execute locally in my browser, or something more automated?

Comment: @HymnZ, one of my comments above was meant for you and not HieuPham, sorry :) Yes I am familiar with created_at_max and created_at_min, but at best this would be only to fetch orders between two dates, and the API would only let me fetch about 50 orders per request :S

Comment: No. You can get all the orders. Use `limit` and `page` parameters. Per call you can get a maximum of 250 items.

Comment: Yes, 50 items per page, 250 items per interval. That would mean several calls, between some of which you have to wait for the API to refresh. What I really want is a simple API call that will fetch turnover between 2 dates like  the browser offers